# Video card not always detected

Tags: boot, graphics-card, reboot

I have this problem since I got a new video card, where the computer does not always detect the card and switches over to the onboard video instead. This only happens when I do a cold boot. It does not happen when restarting the machine via the OS or when coming out of standby. There are no beeps, and the computer will load the OS regardless. If I reboot the machine using the case switch a few times, eventually the video card will get detected and everything will be okay. Setting the video card priority to PCIe in BIOS does not seem to make a difference.

```
Video card: 512MB NVIDIA GeForce 210 (BFG Tech)
Motherboard: eMachines EMCP73VT-PM
PSU: Thermaltake TR2-430NL1NH
OS: The problem happens in both Windows 10 Home 64-bit and Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit SP1.
```

What is causing this issue? It's hard to diagnose since it could be a problem with any of the three hardware components I listed.

[edit]

Here's the BIOS info.

[image]

No BIOS listed for [download here](http://www.emachines.com/ec/en/US/content/drivers.html).

Comment: Are you able to disable the on-board GPU/video card? Also consider checking to see if there is a firmware upgrade available for the BIOS.

Comment: eMachines still exist?!

Comment: No, I have had this problem for several years. I'm just posting about it now.

Comment: I'm not sure I can disable the onboard video totally. I will give it a shot.

Comment: I just checked and noticed that the onboard video is already disabled in BIOS.